# Running PHP File on a Cronjob in cPanel

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a file called automate.php with a mysql connection string and a few PHP/SQL Queries and I want to run the file on a Cronjob.

I have tried just using the full URL like:

```
http://www.domain.com/script.php
```

the local path:

```
/home/your_username/public_html/script.php
```

and also:

```
php -f -q /home/your_username/public_html/script.php
```

i get an email every time it is run and its just saying: *No input file specified.*

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: And what `$ php /home/your_username/public_html/script.php` returns ?

Comment: When there is no rows returned in my SQL Query it just echoes text saying 'No Emails To Send';

Comment: the server is sending the email every time the cron job is run with the results/errors

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272700/running-php-file-on-a-cronjob-in-cpanel/19272999#19272999

Answer (score 3):

use this command

for every 5 minite

```
*/5 * * * * wget http://www.domain.com/script.php
```

Comment: Better to not have cron scripts available in the webroot

Comment: It's not about if it's working fine. Having people figure out they can call a cron script from the URL can lead to very unwanted results. Use a local path.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a permissions issue.  Make sure that the cron runner user has executable permissions on this php file.  Also make the file executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/script.php
```

At the top of the file add:

```
#! /usr/bin/env php
```

Now the script should be able to run on its own:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/script.php
```

Comment: it now says /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: /home/integra/public_html/automate/integra/scripts/send_queued_emails.php: Permission denied

Comment: I have added what you said (#! /usr/bin/env php) right at the top of the php file

Comment: @user2710234 when you look at the permissions for that file are you sure it's executable by the cron user?

Comment: it now says - No such file or directory but its putting : at the end of the URL when i use the full url including domain name

Answer (score 0):

you should have your server domain + your script path
i.e.
http://server.domain.net/myscriptfolder/script.php which is http://server.domain.net absolut domain of your hosting/domain provider.
In my case this works...

Answer (score 0):

if wget does not work try

curl "http://url.com/script.php"

instead of

wget http://url.com/script.php

Answer (score 0):

use this command

> **php-cli** script.php